# PHP Included files writing their own content from Importer values 

Tags: php, dynamic, include

I have a index.php file that will include several external files:

"content/templates/id1/template.php"
"content/templates/id2/template.php"
"content/templates/id3/template.php"
etc.

All these files are loaded dynamically into index.php (it reads all folders inside "templates" directory and then includes every "template.php" file).

I want to make "template.php" to have the same code in all the "id1,id2,id3" folders, BUT to load values from index.php depending in which folder it stays..

How can I do that?
Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have each template find out its directory like so:

/id1/template.php

```
 $path = dirname(__FILE__);
 $id  = pathinfo($path,  PATHINFO_BASENAME);

 echo "Hi, I'm the template in $id!";  // Will output "id1"
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It's a hard life to be a newbie like me :D

Comment: Oh one more question please..

How will I write the code to load from index.php let's say the value of $id1_title (the "id1" is same as the folder where it's placed)?

Comment: Found it on About.com

$test = "success";

$open = "$";

$close = ";";

$primary = "test";

$ID = "$open$primary$close";

echo $ID;

Thanks again Pekka!